# PerformCallback on ASPxCallbackPanel doesn't seem to end

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, callback, devexpress

We are using the ASP.NET controls from DevExpress.

In our application we use  the `ASPxCallbackPanel` control at various places. the callback is triggered by `"CallbackPanel.PerformCallback (...)"` inside a handler of `ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged` .

Sometimes, and only when using Internet Explorer, the loading bar and the form gets locked. We do not get any server error - the client is just showing the loading bar, and doesn't stop.

The recommended error handling for callback errors is set in our Web.Config as follows:

..

```
<modules>
     <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
     <remove name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
     <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
     <add name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
</modules>
```

..

```
<devExpress>
     <compression enableHtmlCompression="true" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true"/>
     <themes enableThemesAssembly="true"/>
     <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="~/sites/special/ErrorPage.aspx"/>
     <settings rightToLeft="false"/>
</devExpress>
```

..

Unfortunately, we can not really reproduce the error. It just occurs sometimes. Is there a way to set a timeout on a callback, so that the loading bar disappears after about 30 seconds? Or ist there a way to redirect to a special error page in the case of a hang?

How can we handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was an Application firewall, we got this solved now.

Comment: I have the same issue :-( Which firewall it was please?

Answer (score 3):

I have answered your question at:

[Loading bar / Form hangs sometimes in Inernet Explorer after CallbackPanel.PerformCallback (...)](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=B198028)

Comment: It seem the problem is that the server is using a firewall which seem to block requests at random. The DevExpress controls should react accordingly if no response is received in a certain time.

Comment: But how.  It seems, that the request does not reach our web application and thus we cannot handle an error...